# How can I render OpenStreetMap tiles on-the-fly using PHP?

Tags: php, openstreetmap

ers, I need to render OSM tiles on-the fly using PHP **without** downloading the huge 23GB or so OSM dump. I found [this](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/PHP_rendering), but it seems to be dead. :/ By the way, I don't want to store anything. If anyone has any ideas, thanks ;)
By the way, I'm using it for a web mapping application for the Nintendo DSi. ([link](http://jsa005.host-ed.me/ntrg/map))

PS. I know I could use the public OSM tile sever, but I hate the tile styles. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very vague.

Instead of using the full [planet](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm) you can download any custom area you like by specifying a [bounding box](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Bbox) using either the [regular API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API) or the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). The latter also allows you to filter for specific data, for example highways. Or you can use a [country extract](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Extract#Country_and_area_extracts).

Alternatively you can just use different tiles if you don't like the default style. There are many many pre-rendered OSM maps with different styles. For example [Cloudmade](http://maps.cloudmade.com/) offers a huge choice of different styles and you can even create your own one.

A third option is to look at one of the many other [rendering applications](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering#Rendering_Software) for OSM.

And whether you are allowed to use the official tiles or not depends on the [tile usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_usage_policy). Note that there are also (different) policies for tiles from different providers.